# Amcharts refresh or validate data every seconds

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using amcharts4 for my data visualization,and I need to validate my data every seconds, my problem here is that it keeps refreshing the whole chart not the data. I used amcharts3 and I tried this method but there is no problem. Is there any way to refresh and validate the data and not the whole chart?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  refresh();
}, 1000);

function refresh(){
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [ {
  "date": "2012-07-27",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-28",
  "value": 11
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-29",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-30",
  "value": 16
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-31",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-01",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-02",
  "value": 22
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-03",
  "value": 23
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-04",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-05",
  "value": 17
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-06",
  "value": 16
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-07",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-08",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-09",
  "value": 26
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-10",
  "value": 24
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-11",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-12",
  "value": 32
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-13",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-14",
  "value": 24
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-15",
  "value": 22
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-16",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-17",
  "value": 19
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-18",
  "value": 14
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-19",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-20",
  "value": 12
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-21",
  "value": 8
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-22",
  "value": 9
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-23",
  "value": 8
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-24",
  "value": 7
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-25",
  "value": 5
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-26",
  "value": 11
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-27",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-28",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-29",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-30",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-31",
  "value": 33
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-01",
  "value": 42
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-02",
  "value": 35
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-03",
  "value": 31
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-04",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-05",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-06",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-07",
  "value": 41
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-08",
  "value": 43
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-09",
  "value": 40
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-10",
  "value": 39
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-11",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-12",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-13",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-14",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-15",
  "value": 42
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-16",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-17",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-18",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-19",
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-20",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-21",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-22",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-23",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-24",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-25",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-26",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-27",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-28",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-29",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-30",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-01",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-02",
  "value": 63
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-03",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-04",
  "value": 32
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-05",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-06",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-07",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-08",
  "value": 28
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-09",
  "value": 27
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-10",
  "value": 36
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-11",
  "value": 33
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-12",
  "value": 31
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-13",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-14",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-15",
  "value": 38
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-16",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-17",
  "value": 44
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-18",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-19",
  "value": 53
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-20",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-21",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-22",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-23",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-24",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-25",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-26",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-27",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-29",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-30",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-31",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-01",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-02",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-03",
  "value": 68
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-04",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-05",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-06",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-07",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-08",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-09",
  "value": 76
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-10",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-11",
  "value": 81
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-12",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-13",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-14",
  "value": 81
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-15",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-16",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-17",
  "value": 86
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-18",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-19",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-20",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-21",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-22",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-23",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-24",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-25",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-26",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-27",
  "value": 79
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-29",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-30",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-01",
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-02",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-03",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-04",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-05",
  "value": 79
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-06",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-07",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-08",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-09",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-10",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-11",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-12",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-13",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-14",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-15",
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-16",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-17",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-18",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-19",
  "value": 53
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-20",
  "value": 54
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-21",
  "value": 56
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-22",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-23",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-24",
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-25",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-26",
  "value": 54
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-27",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-28",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-29",
  "value": 51
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-30",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-31",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-01",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-02",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-03",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-04",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-05",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-06",
  "value": 63
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-07",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-08",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-09",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-10",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-11",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-12",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-13",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-14",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-15",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-16",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-17",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-18",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-19",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-20",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-21",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-22",
  "value": 88
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-23",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-24",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-25",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-26",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-27",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-28",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-29",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-30",
  "value": 81
} ];

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;

// Add vertical scrollbar
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.marginLeft = 0;

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomY";
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Here is my correct code for rendering my chart but not real time

```
//get data from database every 2secs
$interval(function () {
    Blooddonation.donationAdmin().then(function(data) {
        app.date = data.data.date; //store the items here
    });
}, 2000);

//initialize chart
function initChart() {
var data = [];
 for(let key in app.date) {
        data.push({
            "date": app.date[key]._id,
            "value": app.date[key].count
        });
  }
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
}

Here is my items from data.data.date:
[ { _id: '2018-12-01', count: 1 },
  { _id: '2018-12-09', count: 2 },
  { _id: '2018-12-15', count: 3 },
  { _id: '2018-12-30', count: 5 },
  { _id: '2019-01-10', count: 2 },
  { _id: '2019-01-21', count: 3 } ]
```

Comment: there are 2 issues which I see and if I understood you correctly. One is that you create your chart inside refresh function and you call it from your timeout function so, the chart is created again and again. second is the data, the data object is not changing so, what you need to do,setTimeout should be calling your function which is responsible to get the data from the back end. Once you observe that there is a change in your data, you should be calling another function to do the creation of amchart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you to check the [dynamic updates section in the documentaion](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Dynamic_updates).

Your chart creation is encapsulated in the `refresh` function. That means if will try to draw the chart every time `refresh` is called. Instead you need to instantiate the chart once and only update the data using the [addData](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#addData_method) method:

```
chart.addData(dataItem, 1);
```

Based on your updated code, you could try something like shown below assuming `app` exists in the context:

```
chart.events.on('ready', function (e) {

    $interval(function () {
        Blooddonation.donationAdmin().then(function(data) {
            app.date = data.data.date; //store the items here

            e.target.addData(app.date.map(function (item) {
                return {
                    date: item._id,
                    value: item.count
                };
            }), app.date.length - 1);
        });
    }, 2000);

});
```

Check the updated example below:

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [ {
  "date": "2012-07-27",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-28",
  "value": 11
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-29",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-30",
  "value": 16
}, {
  "date": "2012-07-31",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-01",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-02",
  "value": 22
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-03",
  "value": 23
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-04",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-05",
  "value": 17
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-06",
  "value": 16
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-07",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-08",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-09",
  "value": 26
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-10",
  "value": 24
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-11",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-12",
  "value": 32
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-13",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-14",
  "value": 24
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-15",
  "value": 22
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-16",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-17",
  "value": 19
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-18",
  "value": 14
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-19",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-20",
  "value": 12
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-21",
  "value": 8
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-22",
  "value": 9
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-23",
  "value": 8
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-24",
  "value": 7
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-25",
  "value": 5
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-26",
  "value": 11
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-27",
  "value": 13
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-28",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-29",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-30",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-08-31",
  "value": 33
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-01",
  "value": 42
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-02",
  "value": 35
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-03",
  "value": 31
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-04",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-05",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-06",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-07",
  "value": 41
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-08",
  "value": 43
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-09",
  "value": 40
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-10",
  "value": 39
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-11",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-12",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-13",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-14",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-15",
  "value": 42
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-16",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-17",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-18",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-19",
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-20",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-21",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-22",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-23",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-24",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-25",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-26",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-27",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-28",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-29",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-30",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-01",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-02",
  "value": 63
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-03",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-04",
  "value": 32
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-05",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-06",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-07",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-08",
  "value": 28
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-09",
  "value": 27
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-10",
  "value": 36
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-11",
  "value": 33
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-12",
  "value": 31
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-13",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-14",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-15",
  "value": 38
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-16",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-17",
  "value": 44
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-18",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-19",
  "value": 53
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-20",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-21",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-22",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-23",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-24",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-25",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-26",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-27",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-29",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-30",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-31",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-01",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-02",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-03",
  "value": 68
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-04",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-05",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-06",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-07",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-08",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-09",
  "value": 76
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-10",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-11",
  "value": 81
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-12",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-13",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-14",
  "value": 81
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-15",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-16",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-17",
  "value": 86
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-18",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-19",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-20",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-21",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-22",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-23",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-24",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-25",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-26",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-27",
  "value": 79
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-29",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-11-30",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-01",
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-02",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-03",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-04",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-05",
  "value": 79
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-06",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-07",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-08",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-09",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-10",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-11",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-12",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-13",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-14",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-15",
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-16",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-17",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-18",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-19",
  "value": 53
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-20",
  "value": 54
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-21",
  "value": 56
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-22",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-23",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-24",
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-25",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-26",
  "value": 54
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-27",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-28",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-29",
  "value": 51
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-30",
  "value": 52
}, {
  "date": "2012-12-31",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-01",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-02",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-03",
  "value": 64
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-04",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-05",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-06",
  "value": 63
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-07",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-08",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-09",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-10",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-11",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-12",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-13",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-14",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-15",
  "value": 73
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-16",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-17",
  "value": 74
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-18",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-19",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-20",
  "value": 82
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-21",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-22",
  "value": 88
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-23",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-24",
  "value": 85
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-25",
  "value": 80
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-26",
  "value": 87
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-27",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-28",
  "value": 83
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-29",
  "value": 84
}, {
  "date": "2013-01-30",
  "value": 81
} ];

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;

// Add vertical scrollbar
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.marginLeft = 0;

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomY";
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;

chart.events.on('ready', function (e) {

  setInterval(function () {
  
    var data = e.target.data,
        item = data[data.length - 1],
        lastDate = new Date(item.date),
        newDate = new Date(lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate() + 2)),
        fullYear = newDate.getFullYear(),
        month = newDate.getMonth() + 1,
        day = newDate.getDate();
        
    if (month < 10)
      month = '0' + month;
      
    if (day < 10)
      day = '0' + day;
        
    chart.addData({
      date: [fullYear, month, day].join('-'),
      value: item.value + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) - 5
    }, 1);
  }, 1000);
});

// chart.events.on('ready', function (e) {
// 
//     $interval(function () {
//         Blooddonation.donationAdmin().then(function(data) {
//             app.date = data.data.date; //store the items here
// 
//             e.target.addData(app.date.map(function (item) {
//                 return {
//                     date: item._id,
//                     value: item.count
//                 };
//             }), app.date.length - 1);
//         });
//     }, 2000);
// 
// });
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: sir supposed that i have this realtime function to push my data into amcharts  for(let key in app.date10) {
        data.push({
            "date": app.date[key]._id,
            "value": app.date[key].count10
        });
    }

Comment: how can I addData using this?

Comment: You should still use `addData` instead of push and I recommend to remove some items from the beginning while add new ones: `var dataToBeAdded = [...]; chart.addData(dataToBeAdded, dataToBeAdded.length - 1);`

Comment: I updated my code, but doesn't work. It adds the new data but it doesn't render the chart with the new data

Comment: @Darlesson does it means that only the last one item in an array should be get not the whole array?

Comment: @JeremyAdriandeVera, could you provide how you are loading the data and a sample of you data?

Comment: @Godshand, [addData](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#addData_method) can add one or more items.

Comment: please see my angular code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529478/how-to-refresh-data-every-seconds-in-amcharts-not-the-whole-chart

Comment: I finally did it! thanks mate for the help, it took a long time